# remote Ipython notebook

Tags: 14.04, ipython

There is a powerful computer(Ubuntu in it) in our office.

We want to use ipython notebook using power of that computer.

That PC owner also uses Ipython on it.

I have tried to connect via ssh, but something goes wrong. 
I used MobaXterm to connect. Who knows how to do it?

P.S. Is there any way to do it live code for local PCs, using Ipython (not needed, will be awesome to know it)

Comment: what is your local computer? Is it Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: @Yaron Yes. Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. Thank you for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `ssh` from your Ubuntu desktop to the Ubuntu powerful server using `X11 forwarding` using:

```
ssh -Y user@remote_ubuntu.server
```

> [man ssh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ssh.1.html)
>
> -Y Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
>                subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

When you'll open the ipython notebook on the remote server, it should open the window in your locale desktop, while using the remote server CPU

**Note: Assuming that your client is a Windows machine:**

- You need to run X-server on your windows machine.

  - [xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is an example for X-server application which runs on Windows.
- You can use putty as described in this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/119792/596917)

After login to remote server:

- Run the following command on the Ubuntu server and set X server Display to be your windows IP address. (*Win_IP* should be replaced with your windows-machine IP)

  export DISPLAY=WIN_IP:0
- Now you can execute `ipython notebook` (or `xeyes`) on the Ubuntu server, and it should be opened on your Windows machine

Comment: Can I use it like: ssh -Y user@192.168.1.1 ? How to do it in windows?

Comment: Yes the command should be something like: `ssh -Y user@192.168.1.1`

Comment: You can do it in windows using the info from this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/119792/596917)

Comment: I mean windows as user PC. Server will stay in Ubuntu

Comment: Assuming that your client is a Windows machine - you can use putty as described in this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/119792/596917)

Comment: I did it. How to use then in my computer? How I can call from my computer

Comment: did you use `ssh -Y` or `putty` to connect to the remote ubuntu server? did you execute `ipython notebook` (or similar command) on the server? what happened? also - what happened when you execute `xeyes` on the ubuntu server?

Comment: If you client is Windows, you will need to run X-windows server on your windows machine, please see edited answer, with link to `xming`

Comment: I used ssh -Y . Ipython is working on server. Xeyes and xclock is working. How to call ipython on client PC?

Comment: Also - execute `export DISPLAY=WIN_IP:0` on your Ubuntu server (replace *WIN_IP* with the IP of your windows-machine)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure SSH access is enabled on the pc you are trying to reach. 
Try to follow this tutorial!
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-ssh-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

About the PS I don't understand what you want to do... 
With ipython/jupyter you can configure the powerful PC to act as server and expose the notebook, by doing this you can use its resources  using only your browser

Take a look here
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html

Comment: SSH is working.

Comment: Ok, if SSH is working you need to enable X11 forwarding in MobaXTerm. Once you are in try to do 
echo $DISPLAY
or to launch xclock